# Python - send notification to Android app after the MySQL database has changed

Tags: android, python, mysql, firebase, push-notification

I'm working on a project on *pythonanywhere.com* and my code in Python (with Flask framework) manages requests of an Android app that wants to access the MySQL database.

The point is that I would like a notification to arrive on the Android smartphone when a row is added to a database table.

If I understand correctly, from Python to Android I can use Firebase Cloud Messaging, but I'm not sure what to use from MySQL to Python: a trigger that calls a script that will send the notification? Or Python listening to the database? Or what else?

Remember that I'm not using personal servers and databases but those offered by the above mentioned domain so I'm not sure I can use everything I want (for example, if I'm not mistaken, it is not possible to implore a UDF).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you using `SQLAlchemy` the best way is the events. So you can do something like this:

```
class Post(db.Model):
     id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     title = db.Column(db.String)
     text = db.Column(db.String)

@db.event.listens_for(Post, "after_insert")
def send_notification(mapper, connection, target):
     push_firebase_notification()
```

Read more details about events of `SQLAlchemy` here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#orm-events

A different way is to use your signals in your models as Beq mentioned.

```
from blinker import Namespace

awesome_signals = Namespace()
model_saved = awesome_signals.signal('model-saved')

class Post(object):
    ...

    def save(self):
        model_saved.send(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have not thought about the simplest thing: when the insert is successful, I directly launch the notification with pyfcm. I do not know if it's a clean thing or not, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the row added from ? If from Flask app you can use Signals in Model to send notification when the new row is added

Comment: It's not a professional project, so I have a simple form on a page and I build the query by filling the various fields. Then I use `engine.execute(query)`. How can I use signals? Should I change something in the way the query is executed?

Comment: In general you may use signals when query is executed but  I am not sure because I don't know app structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have not thought about the simplest thing: when the insert is successful, I directly launch the notification with pyfcm. I do not know if it's a clean thing or not, but it works.